# present or past tense in conditional sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions, if

Look at the following sentence:

> The importance of leisure time would be more vivid if we **consider / considered** that
> too much work will result in burnout.

Which one is correct? consider or considered?
I think both are correct but the meaning is different:

- If we use consider (First conditional): It only means that leisure time is important.
- If we use considered (Second conditional): It means that we do not consider it; therefore,
  the importance of leisure time is not vivid.

Am I correct?

Comment: What do you think? And are you familiar with the different types of conditional structures?

Comment: Either *It **would** help if we **knew** the answer* OR *It **will** help if we **know** the answer*, depending on how "unreal, hypothetical" you want to imply the possibility is. OR if you want to go all-out syntactically correct / formal / dated, include the subjunctive form *It **would** help if we **were to know** the answer* (with your exact example, *The importance of leisure time would be more vivid if we **were to consider** that too much work **would** result in burnout*, but that would be getting a bit too "wordy" for most people).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I updated my question. Could you please look at it again? I wonder if we can use "would" in first conditional. I've read somewhere that "might" and "should" can be used in first conditional. Is ti also true for "would"?

Comment: I don't think "numbered conditionals" are useful concepts for learning English. But your *actual* example sentence is a bit complicated for the general construction we're looking at here, so let's stick with my *It would help if we knew the answer* version (which has *exactly* the same basic structure, but is easier to understand and work with). You can certainly say *It **might** help if we knew the answer* (less commonly, *It should help if we knew the answer*). Where both are more "tentative" than the original ***would*** version, which asserts that *if* we knew, it would *definitely* help.